# Via PowerShell get the Device Id as shown via System About on any system that has Windows 10/11 installed?

Tags: powershell

Via PowerShell get the Device Id as shown via System About on any system that has Windows 10/11 installed?

The product id, seems to actually be the computer system serial number, but the device id is completely different.  Unfortunately, Get-ComputerInfo does not seem to expose the device id.  Nor is the device id a typical UUID given the format below:

XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Apparently... Get-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient | Select -ExpandProperty MachineID returns the same value, but is there a cleaner way to get said value?